# Angular 2 RC-4 forms, Type 'FormGroup' is not assignable to type 'typeof FormGroup'

Tags: angular, forms, typescript

I am having some trouble with Angular 2 forms, I succesfully implemented a few forms in my project and when I try to add this one, i get and error from my Angular Cli: 
**`Type 'FormGroup' is not assignable to type 'typeof FormGroup'.`**

Anyone met with this ?

Here is my component code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {AngularFire} from "angularfire2/angularfire2";

import {DataService} from "../../shared/data.service";
import {FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators} from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'tm-address-book',
  templateUrl: 'address-book.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['address-book.component.css'],
  providers: [DataService]
})
export class AddressBookComponent {
  myAddressForm = FormGroup;
  addressbook: Array<any>;

  constructor(private af: AngularFire,
          private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
          private dataService: DataService) {
  af.database.list('Addressbook').subscribe(address => {
    this.addressbook = address;
    console.log(this.addressbook);
  });

  this.myAddressForm = formBuilder.group({
    'companyName': ['', Validators.required],
    'street': ['', Validators.required],
    'city': ['', Validators.required],
    'postCode': ['', Validators.required],
  })
}
```

And here is the html form code:

```
<form [formGroup]="myAddressForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="companyName" name="companyName" placeholder="Nazwa firmy">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="street" placeholder="Ulica">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="city" name="city" placeholder="Miejscowość">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="postCode" name="postCode" placeholder="Kod pocztowy">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success waves-effect waves-light" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse1">
              Dodaj
            </button>
          </form>
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I guess you messed up `=` with `:`.

Change your `myAdressForm` definition to this:

```
export class AddressBookComponent {

   myAddressForm : FormGroup;
   ...
}
```

The way you typed it (`myAdressForm = FormGroup`), will assign the property `myAdressForm` to the class type of `FormGroup`

Comment: Correct... This will put me into grave someday. It's the second time I failed on this type / value assignment... Thank you

Comment: Thanks man ... i hope there will be day when my TypeScript linter will become smart as you are.

Comment: @PierreDuc - any clue on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54515500/spring-angular-unable-to-upload-same-file-twice

Comment: @MatWaligora, You should probably accept the answer as it worked and you agreed!

Answer (score 0):

Try once, its work

```
registerForm =new FormGroup({});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation and Angular CLI started to show me some strange errors into html template.
The error message was:

```
Type 'FormGroup' is not assignable to type 'FormGroup'
```

I tried to change from this:

```
loginForm: FormGroup;
```

To this:

```
loginForm = new FormGroup({});
```

It works and the reason why it works it's because the second case initialize controls of formBuilder.