# Spring + Angular Unable to upload same file twice

Tags: java, angular, spring, typescript, spring-boot

Unable to upload same file twice. If uploading different files its working

Error under Network in chrome

```
{ timeStamp: ......, status: 417
  error: 'Bad Request',
  message: 'Required request part 'file' is not present'
  path: 'url as hosted on Tomcat'
}
```

Spring Boot Controller.java file

```
@PostMapping("/Post")
public ResponseEntity<String> handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") 
MultipartFile file){ String Message=""; try .......(and so on)}
```

My Angular Component

```
<form [formGroup]="uploadForm" (ngSubmit) = "onSubmit()">
<input type="file" id="selectFile" formControlName="file1" name="selectFile"
(change)="fileEvent($event)"/>

<input type="submit" name="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Component.ts file

```
fileEvent(e) {
 this.data = e.target.files[0];
}
onSubmit() {
  let headers: any = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-type', 'undefined');
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("file", this.data);
  const req5 = new HttpRequest('POST', 'url as hosted on TOMCAT', formData,
  reportProgress: true,
  responseType: 'text'
  });
  return this.httpClient.request(req5).subscribe(e => {(
  console.log(e);
  )}
}
```

Where am I making a mistake?

Comment: Copy request as curl on 2nd time and paste it, Devtools -> Networks -> Right click in request -> copy as curl

Comment: Off the top of my head, this sounded like perhaps your browser is caching the GET/POST request and that the endpoint was not even being hit.  As your endpoint is being hit, maybe there is some other reason.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - I know the problem also but dnt know the soltn to it.  problem:  angular is looking only on change hence when there is no change to the file being uploaded it will not work

Comment: What version of Angular and Spring Boot are you using?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen its Angular 5

Comment: you should copy and paste your entire `onSubmit` code. It will be better to spot the mistake. With your current code it should not work at all, because you have `omSubmit()` vs `onSubmit()`. The header `content-type` never gets send, because `.append` returns a new header object and `formData` contains `selectFile` field while the server expects a `file` field

Comment: @PierreDuc - yeah sorry i apologize i have made those changes like replacing selectFile with File & onSubmit. i was able to send different files to server but when i am trying to upload same file more than once i am getting error HTTP 400

Comment: @Olivia I can only imagine that somewhere in your code you set `this.data` to undefined again. Best thing you can do is check the network request tab and see what's send to the server. Compare the first request with the second one, and see what's different

Answer (score 1):

Your problem sounds like there is browser caching, whereby the first time the request goes through, and the second time something different happens.  If this be the source of the problem, then you may try appending a random query parameter to the end of the POST URL, e.g.

```
var url = 'url as hosted on TOMCAT';
url = url + (new Date()).getTime();
```

Yes, it may seem strange to bind a query parameter to a POST request, but there should be nothing preventing you from doing this.  Ideally, this would be enough to disable browser caching.

Comment: You certainly _can_ change the URL to anything you wish on the UI side.  This includes adding a query parameter which would probably just be ignored by the server.  I will leave this answer up in case it helps some other reader of your question.

Comment: okay NP but in my case i am getting 404 error by server, it means URL not recognized :(

Comment: Then maybe Spring Boot is considering that extra query param as meaning a different URL resource.  Bummer.  Don't have a workaround for you :-(

Comment: adding a question mark might work, making it `url += '?' + Date.now()`;

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure that the problem is caused by the change-listener on the input field which won't fire again for the same file and you are setting the `this.data` to null after the first submit.

You need to reset the field by ex.: doing it "manually":

```
onSubmit() {
    // upload the file ...
    document.getElementById("selectFile").value = "";
}
```

which ist probably not the best option with Angular.
Or by reseting the form:

```
onSubmit() {
    // upload the file ...
    this.uploadForm.reset();
}
```

[Same answer in German](https://de.jberries.com/frage/gleiche-datei-kann-nicht-zweimal-hochgeladen-werden-21)